# Are “Get” or “Grasp” stative or dynamic verbs?

Tags: meaning, grammar, synonyms, stative-verbs, dynamic-verbs

In Merriam–Webster, the definition of *understand* is as follows:

> to get the meaning of something / to grasp the meaning of something.

Now my questions are regarding a sentence like:

> I don’t understand your instructions.

1. Is it grammatically correct if I rewrite this sentence with present simple, using *get* and *grasp* instead of *understand?*

   > I don't get the meaning of your instructions.
   >
   > I don't grasp the meaning of your instructions.
2. Do these sentences express the same meaning?
3. I know *understand* is a stative verb but are *get* and *grasp* stative or dynamic verbs here? Would the sentence mean the same, if I used present continuous:

   > I don’t understand your instructions?

Answer (score -1):

"I am not getting the meaning of your instructions" - no one would ever really say this, it would be, "I don't get your instructions."

Or even, "I don't get what you mean, these instructions make no sense." So I would say get is a stative verb here.